# ffmpeg exec command not running in nginx rtmp

Tags: ffmpeg, nginx, rtmp, hls

I am using nginx and rtmp module to stream live hls and mpeg-dash.
here is my rtmp command in nginx .conf

```
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1936;


    application mypull {
    live on ;
    meta copy;
    allow play all;

    pull rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/BigBuckBunny_115k.mov name=test live=1;


    exec_push   /usr/bin/ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://localhost:1936/mypull/$name -vcodec libx264 -acodec libmp3lame -f flv rtmp://localhost:1936/hls/$name;


}


application dash {
        live on;
        dash on;
        dash_path /tmp/dash;
        dash_nested on;
        dash_fragment 5s;
        dash_playlist_length 30s;
    }
     application hls {
        live on;
        hls on;
    hls_playlist_length 30s;
    hls_fragment 5s;
        hls_path /tmp/hls;
    }
}
}
```

but it is not playing. it seems that the ffmpeg command is not even running. and the hls and dash folders are empty. could anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven’t figured it out yet, I had a very similar problem and the solution was to fix the permissions of ffmpeg.

Please see here for reference > https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/898#issuecomment-280203062

You should
`chmod -R 755 /usr/bin/ffmpeg` 
and hopefully will work.

my rep is low, I couldn’t comment-ask if you have tried giving the right permissions, so I am sorry in advance if my answer is not helpful.